# What exactly happens when I type "startx" in the command line?

Tags: xorg, window-manager, x-server, startx

I would like to understand what happens when I type `startx` on a modern Linux* machine internally. Can anybody explain this process, step by step?

<sub>* Debian GNU/Linux, if it cannot be generalized to all distributions</sub>

Answer (score 0):

From [startx(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/startx):

> The startx script is a front end to xinit that provides a somewhat
>   nicer user interface for running a single session of the X Window
>   System. It is often run with no arguments.

[And this is where it came from. (link)](https://askubuntu.com/a/519164/391854)

It runs an XServer and a window manager. The details are too long so I'll give links.

It's actually a good read.